# OpenProject Removes Access to Site Root

Tags: http-status-code-403, ubuntu-18.04, openproject

OpenProject installed to `example.net/openproject` per [instructions](https://www.openproject.org/download-and-installation/) on a rented Ubuntu 18.04 server. The site at `example.net/` is no-longer accessible. Getting a 403 Error. How do I fix this?

Comment: The packaged installation of OpenProject was designed for a vestal server, not for one, where an additional application is delivered by the same web server. What is your desired setup?

Comment: I would like to be able to run additional services on the same server. I would like to run OpenProject on a sub-domain and possibly have the root available to host a landing-page/site with instructional videos, links to other services, etc.